# How to split merged cells in a CSV file using python

Tags: python, csv, split

Is there any way to split/unmerge cells in a CSV file using python? What I want is explained below -

[image]

The result should a new CSV file with following entries -

[image]

The text version looks somewhat like this:

```
Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,
A,A1,A11,A111,A1111,
B,B1,B11,B111,B1111,
,,,,B1112,
,,,,B1113,
,,,,B1114,
,,,,,
,,,,,


Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,
A,A1,A11,A111,A1111,
B,B1,B11,B111,B1111,
B,B1,B11,B111,B1112,
B,B1,B11,B111,B1113,
B,B1,B11,B111,B1114,
,,,,,
```

I understand that there's a solution to unmerge excel workbooks, but I havent found a way to do this for CSV files. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What you showed appears to be a picture of a spreadsheet program.  What does the actual CSV file look like?  In general CSV files don't have anything like "merged cells".

Comment: @BrenBarn the data has been extracted from Tableau into a CSV file, when opened in excel, it looks similar to what is shown above

Comment: Can you paste a sample of the raw CSV contents (of your first example) into the text of your post?  (Open the file in a text editor, not Excel, and copy the first several lines.)

Comment: Sorry about the naive-ness, I'm extremely new to all of this.. can you help

Comment: Looks like a job for pandas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done fairly simply with [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
d = pandas.read_csv('your_file.csv')
d.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
d.to_csv('new_file.csv', index=False)
```

Basically this just forward-fills empty cells in each column with the most recent real value.

Answer (score 1):

Of course `pandas` is the right answer. Regardless, here is a non-Pandas solution:

```
import csv
from itertools import izip_longest

with open('input.csv') as input_file:
    input_file = csv.reader(input_file)
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as output_file:
        output_file = csv.writer(output_file)

        previous_row = []
        for row in input_file:
            if any(row):
                row = [a or b for a,b in izip_longest(row, previous_row, fillvalue='')]
            previous_row = row
            output_file.writerow(row)
```

Comment: The pandas answer works Rob, thanks for replying though!