# Filling In Empty Data Sets

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I am currently working on a data science project where the dataset looks something like this:

**Example Dataset:**

[image]

As I'm cleaning the dataset, I notice that the first 4 values in the first column (1,2,3,5) have the same 'Patch Area' of 2500, and the same for the rest. But the dataset I was given only puts 'Patch Area' in the first row of the category. Is there any method where I can fill in the empty cells with their corresponding area so it looks like this:

I created this chart with markdown so I don't actually know how to code it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try with pandas:

```
d = pandas.read_csv('your_file.csv')
d.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
d.to_csv('new_file.csv', index=False)
```

"Basically this just forward-fills empty cells in each column with the most recent real value."

Answer taken from 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38443822/12460726

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this to fulfill a column based on a condition

```
df = pandas.read_csv('your_file.csv')
df.loc[df['Patch Area'] == '', 'Patch Area'] = 2500
```

Here it says `for all value in 'Patch Area', select empty value, and set 2500`